# oracle sql how to get the unmatch positive records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

hello guys I need a little help writing  a sql statement that would basically point out the rows that don't have a corresponding negative matching number, based on my_id,report_id.

Here is the table declaration for better explanation.

```
   CREATE TABLE ."TEST"  
   ( "REPORT_ID" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),  
"AMOUNT" NUMBER(17,2),  
"MY_ID" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),  
"FUND" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),  
"ORG" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)  
   )
```

here is some sample data

```
Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('1',50,'910','100000','67120');

Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('1',-50,'910','100000','67130');

Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('1',100,'910','100000','67150');

Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('2',200,'910','100000','67130');

Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('2',-200,'910','100000','67120');
INSERT INTO TEST (REPORT_ID, AMOUNT, MY_ID, FUND, ORG) VALUES ('1', '40.17', '910', '100000', '67150')  
INSERT INTO TEST (REPORT_ID, AMOUNT, MY_ID, FUND, ORG) VALUES ('1', '-40.17', '910', '100000', '67150')  
INSERT INTO TEST (REPORT_ID, AMOUNT, MY_ID, FUND, ORG) VALUES ('1', '40.17', '910', '100000', '67150')
```

if you create the table and look closely ,  you'll notice that by report_id and my_id most positive amounts have a direct negative amount. In the other hand, I need to identify those positive amounts that do not have a corresponding negative amount by my_id , and report_id.

expected result should look like this

```
"REPORT_ID"                   "FUND"                        "MY_ID"                       "ORG"                         "AMOUNT"                      
"1"                           "100000"                      "910"                         "67150"                       "40.17"                       
"1"                           "100000"                      "910"                         "67150"                       "100"
```

any ideas how can acomplish this.

***EDIT:***
Posted the wrong output result. Just to be clear the fund and org don't matter until after the match. For example if i was writing this using plsql i would find how many minuses do i have then how many pluses do i have compare each plus amount to each minus amount and delete them then i would be left with whatever plus amounts did not have negative amounts. 
I apologize for the confusion. hope this makes it clearer now. once i have all my matches i should end up with only positive amounts that are left behind.

**EDIT:**

```
additional inserts

Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('5',71,'911','100000','67150');
Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('5',71,'911','100000','67120');
Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('5',71,'911','100000','67140');
Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('5',71,'911','100000','67130');
Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('5',71,'911','100000','67130');
Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('5',71,'911','100000','67130');
Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('5',-71,'911','100000','67150');
Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('5',-71,'911','100000','67150');
Insert into TEST (REPORT_ID,AMOUNT,MY_ID,FUND,ORG) values ('5',-71,'911','100000','67150');
```

Comment: Very refreshing to have all of the data ready to work with in the question! Please can you just clarify why 200 is shown in the output above as there is a corresponding -200 row?

Comment: what about the org? should that be ignored?

Comment: answer to above 2 comments, then people would be able to give you some quries.

Comment: @miguel:do you mean in a group of report_id and my_id ,if any record with negative amount found filter that group? or only negative amount need to be filtered?

Comment: @ chris the 200 is in there because theres not another 200 with the same my_id, report_id,negative amount

Comment: @mucio for purposes of calculating we can ignore the org and fund.

Comment: @gaurav yes, the report_id , my_id is the basis for the group calculation so if an element has same group id, same my_id as another row then we can consider that element matched and it is not nessesary to show in query only the element that do not have a match is what im looking to show in my query.

Comment: @Miguel unless I a misunderstanding something there is a -200 in the insert statements you provided with the same report_id and my_id values as the positive 200. Please could you also clarify what should happen with the 40.17 which has two positive and one negative with the same report_ids and my_ids.

Comment: @Chris there are two positive 40.17 and one negative 40.17 therefore we should match atleast one of the positives with one of the negatives and show the positive 40.17 and yes there is a negative 200 btu the report id is different from the others and it matches the 200 with the same report id of 2 is actually easier to see if you create a table ;-D.

Comment: @Miguel I have created a table, but I may have misunderstood the requirement. I thought they if they report_id and my_id matches and the positive amount matched the negative amount then they would cancel each other out and neither would be shown?

Comment: @ChrisProsser my fault i made an error when posting my result based on the insert statement the output is not correct now i see your confusion. I'm very sorry your understanding is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Version**

This should return just the rows that you want. If you are not concerned with org or fund then you can just use the query that is aliased x:

```
select distinct t1.report_id, t1.fund, t1.my_id, t1.org, t1.amount
  from test t1,
      (select distinct t.report_id, t.my_id, abs(amount) as amount
         from test t
        group by t.report_id, t.my_id, abs(amount) 
       having sum(t.amount) > 0) x
 where t1.report_id = x.report_id
   and t1.my_id = x.my_id
   and t1.amount = x.amount;
```

**Previous Version**

```
select * 
  from test t
minus
select t1.*
  from test t1,
       test t2
 where t1.amount = -1*t2.amount
   and t1.report_id = t2.report_id
   and t1.my_id = t2.my_id;
```

This just gives on row of output for the row with amt 100. I have asked you to clarify in the comments why any row with 200 should be included (if it should). I am also not sure whether you want one of the 47.17 values to be included. The difficulty with this is that the two positive values are identical in the example data you provided, is this correct?

Comment: it is correct i should end up with a 40.17 because there are two one pos and one neg. two of then cancel each other therefore the one single positive should come out.

Comment: I just updated with the edit you were right all along i apologize im an idiot.

Comment: @Miguel don't worry about it, mistakes happen.

Comment: chris this is very close to the answer. I will add the additional insert statement that for some reason makes this fail.

Comment: look above for some reason when i add the following insert statement it picks up too many 71's? i expect 3 71's to come back but 4 of them come back any ideas?

Comment: @Miguel I did not build the query for an example like this because it was not in the original post. Can you explain the logic behind which three should remain? I get that there are 6 + and 3 - rows for this amount, so you should be left with 3, but which three? Some of the 6 positive entries for this amount are not the same for all fields. As there appear to be duplicate rows and no clear way of knowing which row should cancel which out I would suggest reviewing the table structure. Some kind of a transaction reference allowing for pairs would make any solution much more reliable.

Comment: thanks chris your comment made me think clearer of what i'm trying to acomplish and your query gets me the answer. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

a modified version  query which works for me for me with your scenario. I used SQL SERVERZ

```
   select * 
  from test t
EXCEPT
select t1.*
  from test t1,
       test t2
 where t1.amount = -1*t2.amount
   and t1.report_id = t2.report_id
   and t1.my_id = t2.my_id;
```

Result with your Data
    REPORT_ID   AMOUNT  MY_ID   FUND    ORG

```
1   100 910 100000  67150
```

the result after running this update query  `update test set AMOUNT=-500 where AMOUNT=-200`

```
REPORT_ID   AMOUNT  MY_ID   FUND    ORG
1   100 910 100000  67150
2   -500    910 100000  67120
2   200 910 100000  67130
```

Comment: amount = -200 should not be in the result based on your data since it has got same report_id and same MY_ID with both 200 and -200 as amout. this be be discarded by the query.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Here's an updated query based on the feedback and additional sample data provided.  This query has the advantage of querying the TEST table just once, and it returns the expected results (3 rows of amount 71, one row of amount 100, and one row of amount 40.17).

```
SELECT
    report_id, MAX(fund) fund, my_id, MAX(org) org, SUM(amount) amount
FROM (
    SELECT
        report_id, fund, my_id, org, amount
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY report_id, my_id, amount ) rn
    FROM
        test
) t
GROUP BY
    rn, ABS(amount), report_id, my_id
HAVING
    SUM(amount) > 0;
```

Results:

```
report_id    fund    my_id    org    amount
5            100000  911      67120  71.00
5            100000  911      67140  71.00
5            100000  911      67150  71.00
1            100000  910      67150  40.17
1            100000  910      67150  100.00
```

**INITIAL ANSWER:**

The below query should provide what you're looking for.  I'm not sure what should be done if org and/or fund are different since you're not grouping on those values - I decided to use a MAX aggregate function on fund and org to select a single value without affecting the grouping.  Maybe those columns should just be left out?

```
SELECT
    report_id, MAX(fund) fund, my_id, MAX(org) org, SUM(amount) amount
FROM
    test
GROUP BY
    report_id, my_id, ABS(amount)
HAVING
    SUM(amount) > 0;
```

Results:

```
report_id    fund    my_id    org    amount
1            100000  910      67150  40.17
1            100000  910      67150  100.00
```

Note that based on the sample data you provided, the expected result should not show 200 because there's a corresponding -200 for the same report_id (2) and my_id (910).

Comment: shawn you are right and this is pretty close but i need to get the fund and org of the unmatched items have been matched. therefore max org will not work for me. Just imagine if you have two pieces of paper in one you would have minus amount and in the other plus amounts. You would use a highliter and higlight based stricly on amount the negative to the positives. Once you are done you would be left with some positive amount and the extra data. That is what im trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Miguel - Consider the following data: <br /><br />`report_id    fund    my_id    org    amount
1            100000  910      67150  60.00
1            100000  910      67151  -60.00
1            100000  910      67152  60.00`<br /><br />We would show an amount of 60.00.  Which org should we show?  67150 or 67152?

Comment: sorry did i miss something where you going to post some data?

Comment: @Miguel - Yes - having a little trouble with comment formatting here.  Hope this works this time.<br/><br/>Consider the following data: <br/><br/>`report_id    fund    my_id    org    amount
1            100000  910      67150  60.00
1            100000  910      67151  -60.00
1            100000  910      67152  60.00`<br/><br/>We would show an amount of 60.00.  Which org should we show?  67150 or 67152?

Comment: either one it does not matter.  but think about having 6 of those positive 60's  and only one -60. than only one pos 60 would match and only one negative 60 would match and i should see the 5 left over rows. it does not matter to which row we match to but it does matter that we see the left over rows that are "unmatched"

Comment: @Miguel - although you've already accepted an answer, I still wanted to post my update based on your additional sample data.